# Need guidance for my duplicated question

Tags: support, asking-questions, exact-duplicates

Today, I wanted to start a bounty on [my question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/9853/7668).

However, I found out it was mark as a duplicate of [this question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/4358/7668).
The thing is, I had read that exact question thoroughly prior to asking the question in case the answer I'm after was lying there.

So I guessing that I'm facing one of the two situations.
**Situation #1 :** The question is really basic and I'm just too much uneducated to get it.

**Situation #2 :** My bad English communication skill came into play and mislead readers about my question. In case this is the case, I've once again edited the question to remove anything misleading about it.

Where did I go wrong and what should I do?

I apologize to bother you with this petty concern.

Comment: Your question got reopened so you can now set a bounty.